# In-place modification of the may attributes list in an LDAP object class

Tags: ldap

I have a pre-existing objectclass that has a good bit of MAY attributes. I have already created the new attributes, but i just need to add them to a pre-exsiting class. Now I can do this using iManager (NetIQ interface to eDirecory) to add the attributes to the class, but I was wondering if I can simply append the attributes to the objectclass for the "MAY" section without first deleting the entire objectclass and re-adding it with the original MAY attributes. I noticed that many have asked this question, but I never see a response that say you can do it and how, or you can't do it. I'm just curious if its possible. Here is a objectclass example:

```
objectClasses: (
```

2.5.6.10
  NAME 'inetOrgPerson'
  STRUCTURAL
  SUP ( organizationalPerson )
  MAY (  employeeID $ employeeType $ givenName $ groupMembership $  uid $ User $ userCertificate $ userPassword )
  X-NDS_NOT_CONTAINER '1'
  X-NDS_NONREMOVABLE '1'
  X-NDS_NAME 'User'
  )

And I would just like to add the new attributes i created (for example "manager" "managerID") to the May section of the object class using ldapmodify so the end result look like this:

```
objectClasses: (
```

2.5.6.10
  NAME 'inetOrgPerson'
  STRUCTURAL
  SUP ( organizationalPerson )
  MAY (  employeeID $ employeeType $ givenName $ groupMembership $  uid $ User $ userCertificate $ userPassword $ manager $ managerID )
  X-NDS_NOT_CONTAINER '1'
  X-NDS_NONREMOVABLE '1'
  X-NDS_NAME 'User'
  )

Again, I know I can delete the entire object class and recreate with the new attributes, or use iManager to do it using its gui. But the question is if its possible to do this in place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to modify the schema of an LDAP directory server is not defined in the LDAP RFCs and thus remains proprietary. Some servers allow to do it over LDAP as a delete and add of the objectClasses attribute in the "cn=Schema" entry (like OpenDJ). Some require that you stop the server and edit schema manually.
Bottom line, it fully depends on the server you are using and it should be part of the product documentation.

Comment: Understood, but the question is can you do a ldapmodify to add additional attributes to a existing class. Or does it "always" call for a delete of the objectclass, and then add that same objectclass back with the additional attributes? This should be the same accross all LDAP protocols.

Comment: It isn't... Adding attributes to an ObjectClass definition is not defined in the LDAP RFCs. Some servers do not allow online modification of the schema. OpenDJ does by allowing a modify operation that deletes one value of the objectClasses attribute under cn=schema and adds another value. I believe that some other products represent each objectClass definition as an entry to which you can add or delete attributes and values from a "May" attribute. Bottom line, different servers uses different methods based on the LDAP protocol, but there is not a standard way to update schema.

Answer (score 0):

Not in OpenDJ. To do this you would need to use

changetype: modify
replace: objectclasses

However, this is not supported on the schema backend, it will work for amending user entries.

You can, although not recommended, amend the schema files directly but this could lead to problems when the server next restarts. If you are on an older version of OpenDJ you can also manage schema through control-panel.

Comment: I'm sorry, you should not "Replace" objectClasses... This would mean to remove all values and provide the whole new set of values. It's possible to do a modification that delete one value and add a new value.

Comment: Exactly, I presume this is why it is not a supported function for the schema backend, I was just trying to give some context to the answer "no" as it is possible to use replace to do other amendments such as user attributes